# How do I add applications to the Messaging Menu?

Tags: application-development, indicator, menu

I would like to have an application appear in the messaging menu that is not installed there by default, is there a way to do that on a per-user basis?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Applications that are in the messaging menu each have a file in the system directory of:

```
/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/
```

That directory contains files that have the paths to the desktop files for those applications.  You can also have one of these in your home directory with this path:

```
~/.config/indicators/messages/applications/
```

So let's say that I want to add Thunderbird to my messaging menu.  I'd do something like this:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications/
$ echo /usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop > ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications/thunderbird
```

You'll need to restart your session (log out and back in) the first time you create the applications directory.

Here's an [example of usage](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/libindicate/trunk/view/head:/examples/im-client.py) from a python application.

Comment: Simply restarting the panel `killall gnome-panel` will work, you don't need to log out.

Comment: Are there any python examples to add functionality to any application added to the Messaging Menu?

Comment: Yes, there are.  Here's a link to them in the libindicate source tree.  You can download it with "bzr branch lp:libindicate" or browse it here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/libindicate/trunk/view/head:/examples/im-client.py

Answer (score 2):

Documentation and example code for doing this can be found [here on the Developer Portal](https://web.archive.org/web/20130730144622/http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/messaging-menu/).

<sub>Editor's note: page no longer exists, so I have replaced the dead link with an archive snapshot from June 2013. Other links on the linked page may be broken and information out of date</sub>

Comment: This page no longer exists.